# Android intent throws an exception when accessing extras

Tags: java, android, android-intent, junit

I'm writing a unit test for a class that produces an intent which contains some data. However, I noticed that when the test tries to verify the required extras in the intent, an exception is thrown.

The code is basically this:

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("FOO", "bar");
assertTrue(i.hasExtra("FOO")); // This is the problem
```

So, the question is: does the intent require some special handling before its extras can be accessed? Is there a function I have to call that I have missed?

Comment: Please share the exception complete stack track.

Comment: @Pallavi It doesn't show up in the stack trace, but when stepping through the test, it goes straight to `ReflectiveCallable` class where an `InvocationTargetException` is thrown.

Comment: You need to pass boolean value to assertTrue. Give a try with assertTrue(i.hasExtra("FOO"),true);.

Comment: @jaydroider `assertTrue` can take just a single argument, and `hasExtra` returns a boolean.

Comment: Can you add some more context? I'd like to know why you're testing whether an extra is added to an intent when you call putExtra on it. Sorry, I'm sure your test is probably more relevant than that, but it just seems like we might be missing something important if your test isn't quite this simple.

Comment: @ajpolt The intent is created in a class from a parsed and validated data. In the unit test I feed this class with input data and expect certain extras to be populated in the intent. In the actual application, the intent is used as an activity's return data container.

Comment: @manabreak assertTrue(getIntent().hasExtra("FOO"));

Comment: @Aks4125 This is a unit test, there's no `getIntent()`.

Comment: By the way, the answer to your actual question is "no." This is the full code in Android v23 for hasExtra(String): "return mExtras != null && mExtras.containsKey(name);" where mExtras is a Bundle. So no, there's nothing you need to do before you can access the extras. Which is why I think it's something more to do with your implementation. More real code would help.